# Extract URL fragment

Tags: python, css, html, url, query-string

Having a hard time finding the URL fragment (the part following the '#' character) using Python 3.3.0. I tried

```
print(os.environ, file=sys.stderr)
```

However neither the `'REQUEST_URI'` or `'QUERY_STRING'` values have the fragment! What is going on and how to get the fragment?

Answer (score 4):

The fragment is never sent by the browser when requesting a URL. It is a client-side-only piece of information.

If you alter *just* the fragment part (with Javascript or manually, in the location bar of your browser), no new request is made to the server; the browser simply updates the page scroll location.

Comment: Ah, that explains it LOL! I am trying to script a different CSS for the target element. Possibly using JS...

Comment: Turns out no such scripting is needed in HTML3, which is another reason to upgrade. All I needed to do was add a css pseudo-element selector like this: `tr:target` and whaddya know it works! Pretty great.